# how to duplicate value in cells based of block value from another cell

Tags: excel

I want to have multiple city numbers and the amount of blocks that are provided in the data given. Here is an image of what I'm looking at and the out put of what I would need it to look like. [image of what would be needed done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eQ6m.jpg)

1. in column A where you see 41288 and in column B where you see an integer value of 4
2. in an empty column lets say C,D,E,F,G,H ..... i want it to space out between cells as shown in column E and F.

   so, i believe the question is how do i space out between the integer number and digit number in (A)?

I know there has got to be a formula. However, not knowing what to ask on Google can get you NO WHERE.

Comment: Should be very easy in VBA. Is that an option?

Comment: Visual basics i can get yes. but not sure how. and will it still export out to excel format ?

Comment: Yes, you'd just have to loop through what you've got in columns A & B then adding values to E & F. It'd be in the same Excel file.

Comment: could you help with that ?

Comment: asside from visual basics can i  use anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The VBA answer (which gives you it in the exact format you were after) is as follows:*

```
Sub DigitBlocks()
Dim rng As Range, a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, e As Double
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

a = Val(Right(Left(rng.Address, InStr(rng.Address, ":") - 1), Len(Left(rng.Address, InStr(rng.Address, ":") - 1)) - InStrRev(Left(rng.Address, InStr(rng.Address, ":") - 1), "$"))) + 1
b = 3

For d = a To rng.Rows.Count
    Range("E" & b).Value = Range("A" & d).Value
    e = Range("B" & d).Value
    For c = 1 To e
        Range("F" & b + c - 1).Value = c
    Next c
    b = b + c
Next d
End Sub
```

---

**Given the amended requirements in comments the answer is now:**

```
Sub DigitBlocks()
    Dim rng As Range, a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, e As Double
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion

    a = Val(Right(Left(rng.Address, InStr(rng.Address, ":") - 1), Len(Left(rng.Address, InStr(rng.Address, ":") - 1)) - InStrRev(Left(rng.Address, InStr(rng.Address, ":") - 1), "$"))) + 1
    b = 3

    For d = a To rng.Rows.Count
        Range("M" & b).Value = Range("J" & d).Value
        e = Range("K" & d).Value
        For c = 1 To e
            Range("N" & b + c - 1).Value = c
        Next c
        b = b + c
    Next d
    End Sub
```

Comment: wow thanks. i'm actually downloading it now. only thing is in IRAQ the internet is super slow. YOU GUYS ROCK

Comment: No worries. I only mention this as you keep flitting between the 2 answers as the accepted one and just to make you aware really; you can only accept one as "the answer" but you can up-vote more than one. Entirely up to you whatever you want to do.

Comment: what if i wanted to do the same thing from column A to K would i just change the for d= a to k=a?

Comment: Do you mean that your range of cities and blocks is in K rather than A or that you've put other information in those columns? a is just the second row of the range, d is the row that the loop is on at that point.

Comment: the image i put on my web server at nashvillekurds.com/new.png

Comment: Ah ok, I'll edit the answer for that as it'll read better that way.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly the format you want, but I think this is as close as you can get with formulas.

Put this into C2:

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(B2=1,"",B2-1))
```

Autofill C2 down, and then autofill the whole column to the right.

You will then have:

```
 41288|4|3|2|1
```

You could then copy&transpose to get the following format

```
 |41288|41289|41290|
 |   4 |   5 |   6 |
 |   3 |   4 |   5 |
 |   2 |   3 |   4 |
 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
 |     |   1 |   2 |
 |     |     |   1 |
```

HTH

EDIT:

Note that even if cells at the end look empty, there's still the formula in there, if you autofilled "too far". You can copy&paste first with only values and then transpose later, if you want the cells to be completely empty.

Comment: Edited a mistake in the formula and the desciption, should work now.

Comment: when i put in the formula it gives an option as logical_test or value if true or value if false

Comment: Hm, works fine for me. Are you sure you also copied all brackets? Also: If you have a different localization than english, you have to use other delimiters or names for excel functions.

Comment: ok i see what you mean and yes it does exactly what you mentioned

Comment: If the answer is working for you, please accept it, so that other users can see, that this question is resolved.

Comment: is there any way i can be able to get the number to be printed down instead of accross